# Which is the best status code or api design when an external client pushes duplicate data?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

We have an integration with an external client that pushes data into our system through a REST API.

For validation issues related to the payload (data transfer objects), we return `422 Unprocessable Entity` if something is not accurate.

Now, when we have scenarios like adding a new user and the user exists on the database, we consider this as a validation error as well, and we don't allow the client to submit the user information because it was already persisted.

Is the `422` status code valid for this type of scenario where we want to avoid duplicate records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status code I would use for this case is `409`. `409` is used in cases where the request body is valid, and it's otherwise a valid request, but the current state of the server prevents the request from being successful.

I wrote more about 409 [here](https://evertpot.com/http/409-confict)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion 422 is definitely suitable for this scenario. As far as I have seen there is no status code that describes an invalid payload because it is a duplicate.

EDIT:
I did not know about 409 but it seems more suitable.